# DStrream[String].foreachrdd on a Spark cluster

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am new to Spark, can anybody help me?

```
def streamStart() {
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("kafkaStreamingNew!!").setMaster("spark://husnain:7077").setJars(Array("/home/husnain/Downloads/ScalaWorkspace/KafkaStreaming/target/KafkaStreaming-1.1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar")) //,"/home/husnain/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10/1.4.1/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10-1.4.1.jar" , "/home/husnain/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming_2.10/1.4.1/spark-streaming_2.10-1.4.1.jar" ,"/home/husnain/.m2/repository/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10/1.4.1/spark-core_2.10-1.4.1.jar" ))
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

val topics = "test";
ssc.checkpoint("checkpoint")
val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, "localhost:2181", "spark", Map("test" -> 1)).map(_._2)
lines.print()
println("*****************************************************************************")
lines.foreachRDD(
  iter => iter.foreach(
    x => println(x + "\n***-------------------------------------------------------***\n")))
println("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------")
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

On a Spark standalone cluster, that code doesn't work, but on local[*], it works correctly:

```
lines.foreachRDD(
  iter => iter.foreach(
    x => println(x + "\n***-------------------------------------------------------***\n")
    )
   )
```

Comment: And what does it mean _it doesn't work_? Or _works correctly_ for that matter.

Comment: I suspect you're submitting your application in the wrong way. Are you using spark-submit? It is rather impossible(in fact very tricky) to submit an application to a cluster from code. Have a look here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: @dwysakowicz yes i am submitting job through spark-submit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what it's being called as "works correctly" is that you see the `println`s on the console.

When you submit the same code to a cluster, the `println` to the console happens locally on each executor, so if everything else is working, the lack of output is solely the result of the distributed execution.

Look in the output of the executors for those `println`s

Comment: i wrote `println` here for shorten  the code. my actual task is to save incoming data into hbase after some computations. on local it works (means save to hbase successfully) but in spark standalone cluster mode it doesn't work :(

Comment: you mentioned hbase.. are you sure you're using right configuration? Are you specifying the connection parameters in code or through *.xml? On workers it may not pick up the right configuration.